# Next JS 13 upgrade breaks on windows 10

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm, next.js13

I took a commit from github before i ran the command npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest

i can build it no prob. then when i ran that command and tried to build it it gives me
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Now on vercel it works and on my macbook pro it work just on my windows 10 pro pc i cant build or even run in dev.

```
68405> npm i
npm WARN deprecated @types/mongoose@5.11.97: Mongoose publishes its own types, so you do not need to install this package.

added 221 packages, and audited 222 packages in 3s

30 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

PS C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website> npm run build

> build
> next build

info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\.env.local
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.   
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at 
https://nextjs.link/app-feedback

Warning: For production Image Optimization with Next.js, the optional 'sharp' package is strongly recommended. Run 'yarn add sharp', and Next.js will use it automatically for Image Optimization.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/sharp-missing-in-production
info  - Creating an optimized production build
warn  - Compiled with warnings

./node_modules/debug/src/node.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'supports-color' in 'C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\debug\src'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/debug/src/node.js
./node_modules/debug/src/index.js
./node_modules/follow-redirects/debug.js
./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/adapters.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js
./node_modules/axios/lib/axios.js
./node_modules/axios/index.js
./app/shop/components/SaleForm.tsx

info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Collecting page data  
info  - Generating static pages (14/14)
info  - Finalizing page optimization

Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      0 B                0 B    
├ ○ /admin                                 163 B          67.2 kB    
├ ○ /region                                  163 B          67.2 kB    
├ ○ /auth                                  965 B          78.6 kB    
├ ○ /shop                                 19.9 kB        97.6 kB    
├ ○ /shop/daily                             166 B          67.2 kB    
├ ○ /shop/management                      166 B          67.2 kB    
├ ○ /shop/monthly                           166 B          67.2 kB    
├ ○ /shop/profile                         166 B          67.2 kB    
├ ○ /shop/quarterly                         166 B          67.2 kB    
├ ○ /shop/returns                         166 B          67.2 kB    
└ ○ /shop/weekly                            165 B          67.2 kB    
+ First Load JS shared by all              67 kB
  ├ chunks/17-2d54602f20b449ab.js          64.7 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-6cef3c43ceb652fc.js    204 B
  └ chunks/webpack-1a28356fdbd282fd.js     2.15 kB

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS    
┌ ○ /404                                   179 B          81.8 kB    
├ λ /api/auth/[...nextauth]                0 B            81.6 kB    
└ λ /api/hello                             0 B            81.6 kB    
+ First Load JS shared by all              81.6 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-5841ab2cb3aa228d.js  192 B
  └ chunks/webpack-1a28356fdbd282fd.js     2.15 kB

ƒ Middleware                               63.3 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or 
getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

PS C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website> npm start

> start
> next start

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\.env.local
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback

Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y


UP TO HERE WORKS FINE NOW I UPGRADE


PS C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website> npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest

added 216 packages, changed 3 packages, and audited 438 packages in 7s

124 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

PS C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website> npm run build

> build
> next build

info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\.env.local
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (appDir) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback

info  - Creating an optimized production build ..<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (659kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Linting and checking validity of types  
info  - Collecting page data  
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/14)SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/shop/returns". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/shop/monthly". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/region". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`enter code here`
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`enter code here`
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/auth". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/shop/profile". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/shop/management". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/shop". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/shop/weekly". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/shop/quarterly". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/admin". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)

Error occurred prerendering page "/shop/daily". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at U (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:22:53)
    at c (C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-client.edge.production.min.js:24:307)
info  - Generating static pages (14/14)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /admin/page: /admin
        /region/page: /region
        /auth/page: /auth
        /page: /
        /shop/daily/page: /shop/daily
        /shop/management/page: /shop/management
        /shop/monthly/page: /shop/monthly
        /shop/page: /shop
        /shop/profile/page: /shop/profile
        /shop/quarterly/page: /shop/quarterly
        /shop/returns/page: /shop/returns
        /shop/weekly/page: /shop/weekly
PS C:\Users\MRSingh\Desktop\Website>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48070, updating to a canary version release v13.3.1-canary.4 should fix your issue.